# How to get jQuery UI Autocomplete working without Hyphens

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, autocomplete

Today I can type a town and jquery autocomplete show me a list of corresponding towns (the source is a database) : OKAY

The problem is that if the name of this town contain an hyphen, then what is typed doesn't match anything.

Example :

if I type "l'abergement sainte colombe" (the user missed an hyphen), then I would like anyway to see "l'abergement-sainte colombe" (the correct name).

Here is my js code :

```
$("#suggest13").autocomplete({
    source:"mysrc",
    minLength:2
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem=function(ul,item){
    // this part below is just to put in bold
    return $("<li>").append("<span>"+item.value.replace(new RegExp("^"+this.term,"i"),"<strong>"+this.term+"</strong>")+"</span>").appendTo(ul);
};
```

and the PHP code called ("mysrc") with the sql query :

```
$stmt = $connexion->query('select name from City_fr where name LIKE "'.$_GET['term'].'%"');

while ($rs=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
   $row['value']=$rs->city_name;
   ...
   $row_set[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I have no idea where you could use regex for this one. Not even for placing hyphen. Unless the position is determined by some pattern and not as per understanding of natural language.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more condition in your query like-

```
select name from City_fr where REPLACE(name, '-', ' ') LIKE "%'.$_GET['term'].'%" OR name LIKE "%'.$_GET['term'].'%"
```

This should work.